# How to read only digits from input (no letters, just digits) in C?

Tags: c, input, error-handling, user-input

You helped me a while ago with reading a line. Now, I want to read only digits from input - no letters, just 5 digits. How can I do this?

My solution doesn't work properly:

```
int i = 0; 
while(!go)
    {
        printf("Give 5 digits: \n\n");
        while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF  &&  c != '\n' &&  i < 5 )
        {
            int digit = c - '0';
            if(digit >= 0 && digit <= 9)
            {
                input[i++] = digit;
                if(i == 5)
                {
                    break;
                    go = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "no letters, no numbers, just digits" - is a digit not a number?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Yes it is, I didnt know how to explain this:)

Comment: Could you please tell us WHAT happens with your code? This would make it easier to diagnose it.

Comment: If a digit and a number are the same thing, then saying "no numbers, just digits" definitely isn't the way to explain it. If there's a distinction between numbers and digits that's relevant to your question (which seems more likely), please explain it.

Comment: `if(i == 5)
                {
                    break;
                    go = true;
                }` The go=true; is not reacheable. BTW: this should be the **loop condition**

Answer (score 2):

With the `break` statement, `go = true;` will never be executed. Therefore the loop `while (!go)` is infinite.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 0;
int input[5];

printf ("Give five digits: ");
fflush (stdout);

do
{
  c = getchar ();

  if (isdigit (c))
  {
    input[i] = c - '0';
    i = i + 1;
  }
} while (i < 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char  c;
        while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF  &&  c != '\n' &&  c >= 48  && c <= 57 )
        {
          printf("%c\n",c);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several mistakes in this code: ```c``` should be an ```int``` (otherwise it will incorrectly identify ```EOF```), the indentation is out, and you are inconsistent with using character literals and their ascii equivalent (e.g. 48 instead of '0'). Additionally, "getchar" both echoes and seems to wait for a newline before returning anyway.

Comment: It also doesn't record input, it attempts to put a newline in between every character, and it doesn't address the question of reading only five digits.