# switch statement convert number to words

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm learning switch statements, I understand the logic and all but my program will nut print the second switch statement. It is reading &digit1 but i dont think its reading &digit2 for the second switch. I've already looked at other posts but I can't find anything to help me, atleast that I can grasp lol. I am not getting any errors but cannot understand why its printing switch (digit1) and not switch(digit2) Thanks for any assistance.
Here is my code as of now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{int digit1;//user's first number
//digit1 = number/10
int digit2;
//digit2 = number%10
int number;;//users second number

printf("Enter a two digit number less than 100:\n");
scanf("%d", &digit1, &digit2);

switch(digit1)
{
case 0:
    printf("zero");
    break;
case 1:
    printf("one");
    break;
case 2:
    printf("two\n");
    break;
case 3:
    printf("three");
    break;
case 4:
    printf("four");
    break;
case 5:
    printf("five");
    break;
case 6:
    printf("six");
    break;
case 7:
    printf("seven");
case 8:
    printf("eight");
    break;
case 9:
    printf("nine");
    break;

switch (digit2)
{
case 0:
    printf("zero");
    break;
case 1:
    printf("one");
    break;
case 2:
    printf("two\n");
    break;
case 3:
    printf("three");
    break;
case 4:
    printf("four");
    break;
case 5:
    printf("five");
    break;
case 6:
    printf("six");
    break;
case 7:
    printf("seven");
case 8:
    printf("eight");
    break;
case 9:
    printf("nine");
    break;
default:
    printf("\nYou must enter a valid number");
    break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &digit1, &digit2);` only reads a single number (which may have more than one digit) into `digit1`.

Comment: your second switch is inside the body of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

`scanf("%d", &digit1, &digit2);`

to this

`scanf("%d %d", &digit1, &digit2);`

Now you can read two numbers of the form `number1 number2`.

---

Moreover you should make the two `switches` independent. Now, the second is inside the first one. The second switch will **never** be executed (even if you reach case 9, you will `break` before it the second `switch`).

You should do it like this:

```
switch(digit1) {
  ...
}

switch(digit2) {
  ...
}
```

---

At the first and at the second `switch` you missed one `break` here:

```
case 7:
  printf("seven");
```

Also in some cases you have the `printf()`'s to print a newline and in some others not. It would be more elegant to have all `printf()`'s behaving the same in regards to the newline.

---

You seem to not using this variable (which also has an extra useless semicolon):

```
int number;;
```

---

An easy way to spot things like these is to turn on your compiler *warnings*, by using the `-Wall` flag for example:

I got:

```
warning: too many arguments for format

warning: unused variable ‘number’

warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

The first one came from `scanf()`, the second from the unused variable I mentioned before and last one comes from the lack of a `return` in your `main()`.

---

In the future you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483006/2411320), which states how to read 5 digits, but I think for a start you are doing it nicely with reading numbers and stating the user not to input a number larger than 9!

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your `scanf`

```
printf("Enter a two digit number less than 100:\n");
scanf("%d %d", &digit1, &digit2);
```

While compiling, enable the warrings and solve those warrings.

```
gcc -Wall foo.c
```

foo.c:12:1: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

foo.c:9:5: warning: unused variable ‘number’ [-Wunused-variable]

foo.c:82:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Your code is having, these many warrings.

Comment: I've never heard of the warning thing! thanks for everyones help, I will test and debug now :)

Comment: Ok, I fixed all my errors but still cant get the user's nu,ber to print out to the screen......i have no idea what's going on

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is picking up the whole number and putting it in `digit1` (you can verify this by looking at the return value of scanf -- I think it will be 1 instead of 2).

What you should do is take the value from `scanf` and then generate the two digits by taking the quotient and remainder on division by 10 (as your comments at the top of the code suggest).

So:

```
sscanf("%d", &number);
number1 = number / 10;  //quotient
number2 = number % 10; // remainder ...
```